# Grouping items based on their category in enum for products - java

Tags: java, enums

I'm new to programming and coding in java. I am making a application for an assignment that allows for products to be entered with different product codes and names etc. Under this they can select what category their product is based on the enum selected.

I was wondering if there is any method to print out the products based on the enum selected for example, all products under "technology" section printed out together and others for the likes of "food" printed out together under different headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely looking for a [groupingBy](http://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector) collector. Essentially, the [groupingBy](http://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector) collector allows grouping objects by some given property and storing the results in a `Map` instance.

After you've done the grouping you can simply retrieve the list of objects that belong to a particular group and print out the data you want to be displayed.

---

if you've already grouped the products and are just interested in printing out all the list of objects based on an enum value, given the `Map` instance storing the groups is declared at the class level then I'd suggest you create a method that takes a single parameter of the enum type, then create a switch statement within the method specifying all the possible values then within each case simply print out the list that corresponds to the `case` value. now it's a matter of invoking this method and passing in the enum value that corresponds to the group you want to be printed.

considering that the `Product` class has overridden the `toString` method everything should work as expected else you'll need to override the `toString` method.

As for the formatting, you're probably looking for the [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) method. you can find more string format examples [here](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples).